# How can I get rails/ngnix to cleanup /tmp/RackMultipart* files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

When a user uploads an image, files like this build up in `/tmp`

```
RackMultipart20101130-1130-1l2q8dt-0
RackMultipart20101130-1130-1t11oa9-0
RackMultipart20101130-1130-59nrpq-0
RackMultipart20101130-1130-6jdqem-0
RackMultipart20101130-11807-1usq3d8-0  
RackMultipart20101130-11807-nns7dw-0
```

How can I get rails / nginx / passenger to clean up these files after the upload is finished?

I'm using:

- nginx 0.8.53
- Phusion Passenger 2.2.15 (mod_rails/mod_rack)
- Ruby on Rails 2.3.8
- Paperclip ruby gem to upload images

Comment: In my understanding the `/tmp` directory on a Unix system is purged automatically (this differs from system to system if I'm right) so I don't see why you would want to do this manually. Could you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: I'm using linux (debian). /tmp is filling up and I don't have complete root access to increase the size of /tmp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is a Rake task with a crontab to clear the `/tmp` directory from time to time.

1. Create a new Rake task in `lib/tasks` which removes the `RackMultipart*` files.
2. Execute the Rake task as a crontab each X hours.
3. (optional) Use [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to simplify step 2 (quite powerful in combination with [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano))

This said it would be better to ask Paperclip clear the files as the approach above could remove a temporary file still in use by Paperclip but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write a Rake task, I would suggest installing the [tmpreaper](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/tmpreaper-cleans-up-files-in-directories-based-on-their-age.html) package for debian/ubuntu.  It can be configured to clean `/tmp` as frequently as desired (e.g., to remove files not accessed in the last hour).

The underlying Papeclip issue [#902](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/902) was resolved with the release of Paperclip 3.1.0, after which we stopped seeing so many RackMultipart* files stick around.